# How to use linq in microsoft.clearscript.v8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, v8

I am using `microsoft.clearscript.v8` in ASP.Net Core MVC. This code is in my Home controller:

```csharp
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    using (var engine1 = new V8ScriptEngine())
    {
        engine1.AddHostType(typeof(JavaScriptExtensions));
        engine1.DocumentSettings.AccessFlags = DocumentAccessFlags.EnableFileLoading;
        string scriptPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "js", "NewScript.js");
        string scriptContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(scriptPath);
        engine1.Execute(scriptContent);
        dynamic data = engine1.Evaluate("NewLinq();");
        return View();
    }
}
```

This code is in NewScript.js

```js
function NewLinq() {
  const rawData = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "John", "age": 25 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Jane", "age": 30 }      
  ];

  var result = rawData.filter(person => person.age > 25);  
  return result;
}
```

The code returns an error:

> UnderlyingSystemType = '((Microsoft.ClearScript.ScriptItem)data).UnderlyingSystemType' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'

How to get output and use linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is the limitation within the ClearScript library when trying to directly interact with the dynamic type returned by the JavaScript execution. Instead of using the `dynamic`, you could try to cast the returned data to a more specific type.

Below is the modified code:

HomeController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    using (var engine1 = new V8ScriptEngine())
    {
        engine1.AddHostType(typeof(JavaScriptExtensions));
        engine1.DocumentSettings.AccessFlags = DocumentAccessFlags.EnableFileLoading;
        string scriptPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "js", "NewScript.js");
        string scriptContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(scriptPath);
        engine1.Execute(scriptContent);
        
        string jsonData = engine1.Evaluate("NewLinq();").ToString();

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonData);

        return View(data);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

NewScript.js:

```
function NewLinq() {
  const rawData = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "John", "age": 25 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Jane", "age": 30 }      
  ];

  var result = rawData.filter(person => person.age > 25);  
  return JSON.stringify(result); 
}
```

Comment: how to use were condition in linq javascript in json data any solution for this